# Remove columns in text files python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have the following text file and would like to remove (open, high, low) from the file completely. I want to be left with: Date, Time, Close, Up, Down

Here is the sample text file:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Up","Down"
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,109,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,0,1
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,0,2
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,1,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,1,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,1,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,1,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,0,2
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,0,5
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,0,1
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,3,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,1,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,2852.50,3,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,3,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,2852.25,0,1
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,7,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,4,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,1,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,12,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2,0
08/09/2018,17:00:00,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,2852.75,1,0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please present a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: a hint, `split('\n')` first, then `split(',')`

Comment: Make a new temporary file. Read from the original file line by line with a `csv.reader`. Or just split the line as mentioned in the comment above. The value at each line will be a tuple `(col1, col2, ...)`. Then just index the row to select the columns you want, and write those new rows to the temporary file. Then when you're done you can copy the temp file over to overwrite the old one...or again iteratively write from the temp one back to the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a library like Pandas is my usual goto when reading in files such as this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample_text_file.txt")
df_new = df[['Date', 'Time', 'Close', 'Up', 'Down']]
df_new.to_csv('sample_text_file_new.txt', header=True, index=None)
```

Comment: The stdlib contains a perfectly suitable `csv` module without invoking a heavyweight external package.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. (1) make sure pandas is already installed (more information about padas is here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/pandas.pdf). (2) this code opened the existing file and deleted the fields I needed deleting and created a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is maybe not the best way, I would suggest reading such a text file into a dataframe using the pandas library [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). (If you want to perform actual data analysis operations on this data, something like Pandas would best serve you as opposed to simple file io reading/splitting.) After you create the dataframe (looking at the documentation for Pandas), use the pandas drop command [Pandas drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

For your case, it would be something like this:

```
#import pandas as pd
#Following creation of Pandas dataframe df
df = df.drop(["Open", "High", "Low"], axis = 1)
```

Make sure you reassign the dataframe after you make the changes. I will leave it as an exercise for you to consult the docs and actually import the dataframe. Look through pandas a little bit, and you should figure it out.